# convert_tz returns null even after loading time zone tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a MySQL database (hosted on Ubuntu) that has a table with a time zone. This date is in the UTC time zone. I have an application that is using this data but needs to convert the time from UTC to PST to display the data in a useful format.

This can probably be changed on the application level, but I don't have the time to do that currently, so what I want to do is use `convert_tz` to get the correct time zone until I have time to change the application to convert the time zone.

However, whenever I do something like

```
SELECT id, 
       category, 
       convert_tz(create_datetime, 'UTC', 'PST') as create_datetime
FROM table
```

I get a result like

```
1, category, NULL
```

I know that I need to load the time zone tables, so I did, running this command:

```
mysql_tzinfo_to_sql /usr/share/zoneinfo | mysql -u root -p mysql
```

After that I restarted the mysql service. However, `convert_tz` still returns `NULL`. Can someone give me a hand?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Make sure that your `create_datetime` colum is of type `TIMESTAMP`.

Please refer to the official MySQL Reference Manual:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_convert-tz

Example:

```
SELECT CONVERT_TZ('2004-01-01 12:00:00', 'GMT', 'MET');
```

Answer (score 1):

When I had this problem it was because I used the wrong time zone name. I incorrectly inferred from the time zone used in the example in the MySQL documentation, MET, that 3-letter US time zones such as PST would work. That's not the case: US time zones are named 'PST8PDT' and the like. So whereas

```
select convert_tz('2016-10-16 06:23:00', 'UTC', 'PST');
```

returns `NULL`,

```
select convert_tz('2016-10-16 06:23:00', 'UTC', 'PST8PDT');
```

returns the converted time.

You can see the time zone names in your MySQL instance with

```
select Name from mysql.time_zone_name;
```

Comment: Thank you this saved us a day of banging our heads against our desks. The rationale for the time zone abbreviations not working in MySQL is that you don't really know which time zone in the abbreviation to use. This matters in that some of the time zones can have different daylight savings rules.